# In latex preview pane mode, make the pane stay where I put it

Tags: latex, preview-latex

Does anyone know how to make the pane in latex preview pane mode stay put? When I move it to the frame/window I would like it to be, it pops back to its default window when I refresh it, M-p.

Edit: Precisely what I mean.

1. Install latex-preview-pane from melpa repo
2. Open any .tex file. C-x C-f "/mydir/myfile.tex"
3. Open a .pdf preview of the .tex file: M-x latex-preview-pane-mode. This will open a new myfile.pdf buffer in a new window to the right of myfile.tex
4. Close the preview window C-x 1
5. Open new frame C-x 5 2
6. Open the myfile.pdf buffer in the new frame using C-x b.
7. At this point I have a preview frame that I can place where ever I'd like, preferably on a second monitor
8. Return to the original window containing myfile.tex, C-x 5 o
9. Make changes to myfile.tex
10. Update the myfile.pdf buffer to reflect changes M-p.

At this point the frame that was created and moved is still in place and updated, but a new window opens to the right of the myfile.tex buffer again with another copy of the preview pane. So I now have two views of the myfile.pdf buffer.

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, preferably starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). So far, it's unclear what you are experiencing (to me, at least).